# type.IsAssignableFrom from generic interface<object> return false

Tags: c#

Why this example prints false?

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool assignable = typeof(Results<Foo>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IResults<object>));            
            Console.WriteLine(assignable);
        }
    }

    public interface IResults<T>
    {
        IEnumerable<T> Items { get; }
    }

    public class Results<T> : IResults<T>
    {
        public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public string Name { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Who says that an `object` is a `Foo`? Isn't that check backwards? Did you mean `typeof(IResults<object>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Results<Foo>))`?

Comment: It prints false because `Result<Foo>` is **not** assignable from `IResult<object>`. The other way round would work if `T` in `IResult<T>` would be covariant (but which it is not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`false` is the right result here. Checking whether `typeof(Results<Foo>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IResults<object>))` is like asking if the following snippet will compile:

```
Results<Foo> a = ...;
IResults<ojbect> b = ...;
a = b; // Will this compile?
```

Assuming `IResults` is an interface that `Results` implements, you cannot assign an `IResults` object to a `Results` reference, as the compiler has no way of knowing whether the runtime type of indeed a `Results` object or not. Thus, returning `false` here makes sense.